# How to find the equation of line in spherical co-ordinate system?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to find the equation of the curve between two points in spherical co-ordinate whose length is shortest, i.e. find the equation of line in spherical co-ordinate system. Here is my work so far,
[image]
Did I do some mistake somewhere? Because I am stuck and don't know how to solve the differential equation,
$$\frac{r}{\sqrt{r'^2+r^2}}-\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{r'}{\sqrt{r'^2+r^2}} = 0$$
Please tell me how to proceed.

P.S. I made a mistake in the final equation, forgot the square-root and r prime. Please ignore.

Comment: You ask for an equation in spherical coordinates but you use only two coordinates. Did you actually want the equation in _polar_ coordinates?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck This is a problem from calculus of variation exercise and the question asked to solve using Euler-Lagrange equation. No, the arc is not any sphere, it is like any other function in polar co-ordinate.

Comment: @DavidK Yes. I confuse a lot between spherical and polar co-ordinates. In my mind, they are essentially same with polar being a 2D version for spherical co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply
$$
ax+by+c=0 \implies ar\cos\theta+br\sin\theta+c=0\implies r=-\frac{c}{a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta}
$$

Anyway, you should perform the derivative, obtaining
$$
\frac{r}{\sqrt{r'^2+r^2}}-\frac{r''}{\sqrt{r'^2+r^2}}+\frac{r'(2r'r''+2rr')}{2\sqrt{(r'^2+r^2)^3}} = 0
$$
and further simplify to
$$
-\frac{r(rr''-2r'^2-r^2)}{\sqrt{(r'^2+r^2)^3}} = 0
$$

Comment: I understand that there are other ways to find the equation of line, but this is a problem from the exercise of Euler-Lagrange equation. The question is to solve using Variational Calculus.

Comment: @Ayatana: see edit

Comment: I solved $-\frac{r(rr''-2r'^2-r^2)}{\sqrt{(r'^2+r^2)^3}} = 0$ using Mathematica and I got $\frac{c_2}{\sec(\theta+c_1)}$, which is indeed a straight line in polar co-ordinates. But you have any idea how to solve that differential equation by hand?

Comment: @Ayatana: with the substitution $u=r'/r$ you get $u'=u^2+1$